# ¿Cuándo es neceserario guardar en una variable local el Iterator en java?

Tags: java

¿Me podrían indicar el motivo por el que es necesario guardar el it.next() del iterator en una variable local? ¿Y por qué es necesario declararse una variable local prev=null en este ejemplo?

```
public boolean estaOrdenado (Iterable<Integer> lista)
{
    boolean loEsta = true;
    Iterator<Integer> it = lista.iterator();
    Integer prev = null;
    if(it.hasNext()){
        prev = it.next();
    }
    while(it.hasNext() && loEsta){
        Integer cursor = it.next();
        if(!(prev.compareTo(cursor)<=0)){
            loEsta = false;
            prev=cursor;
        }
    return loEsta;
    }
```

Comment: 1. Se guarda porque el valor que tenga `next()` en ese momento se necesita más adelante. 2. Se declara antes porque si la declaras dentro del `if` y el código no pasa por allí, al querer usarla más adelante tendrías un NPE. Dicho esto, la lógica del código parece cuestionable, pero como no sabemos lo que hace en sí, nada más se  puede decir.

Comment: Con este código pretendo saber si la lista está ordenada de menor a mayor

Comment: @A.Cedano pones eso como respuesta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Se guarda porque el valor que tenga `next()` en ese momento se necesita más adelante.
2. Se declara antes porque si la declaras dentro del `if` y el código no pasa por allí, al querer usarla más adelante tendrías un NPE.

Dicho esto, la lógica del código parece cuestionable, pero como no sabemos lo que hace en sí, nada más se puede decir.

Si se trata de saber si la lista está ordenada, puedes hacer algo así más o menos:

```
public static boolean isSorted(List<Integer> listOfIntegers) {
    if (isEmpty(listOfIntegers) || listOfIntegers.size() == 1) {
        return true;
    }
 
    Iterator<Integer> iter = listOfIntegers.iterator();
    Integer current, previous = iter.next();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        current = iter.next();
        if (previous.compareTo(current) < 0) {
            return false;
        }
        previous = current;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Para otras posibilidades [ver aquí](https://www.baeldung.com/java-check-if-list-sorted).

Hay comparaciones más avanzadas que se pueden hacer con lambda. Aquí se propone una solución basada en `Iterator` usando `compareTo()`.